# AWS Glue - DynamoDB with On-Demand Capacity Super Slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We have an AWS Glue job that is pulling from the a dynamodb table which is set to on-demand capacity.  However, once we changed the table to on-demand, the glue job is taking forever to complete.

Presumably the glue job is trying to use a portion of the available read capacity...but this doesn't make sense with the new capacity model.

We are hoping to move all of our tables to the new on-demand capacity setting, but this would be a blocker for us.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a new table that has never used provisioned capacity?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee, nope.  This was a table we recently switch from normal capacity  to on-demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When the DynamoDB table is in on-demand mode, AWS Glue handles the read capacity of the table as 40000. For exporting a large table, we recommend switching your DynamoDB table to on-demand mode."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html

The below is no longer true

---

As per AWS [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) On-demand is currently not supported by AWS Data Pipeline, the DynamoDB import/export tool, and AWS Glue. So you need to carefully chose which tables you want to move to new on-demand capacity.